# Coloring a JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, colorize

I am struggling with a problem on coloring an array of JButtons.

I made two arrays of JButtons:

```
public JButton Speler1[] = new JButton[140]; //Player1
public JButton Speler2[] = new JButton[140]; //Player2
```

These two arrays of buttons make lane 1 and lane 2 of a racing game. I want the position of player 1 and 2 to be colored on both screens. So player 1 can see where player 2 is and vice versa.

I already made a method which sends the position of both players to eachother.

```
if (message.contains("Positie")) {
   String posit = message.replaceFirst("Positie", "");
   int positi = Integer.valueOf(posit);
   positie2 = positi;
   kleurHokje kleur = new kleurHokje();
   kleur.hokVerkleur(positi); // positi is the position of each player
}
```

So when I call the method hokVerkleur(positi), I want to change a button on lane 2.

```
class kleurHokje{
    public void hokVerkleur(int loc){
        Speler2[loc].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        Speler2[positie2].setBackground(Color.gray);                
    }
}
```

It just wont work. While i'm doing almost the same for Speler1[positie] except Speler1 doesn't use the network, which works as I want.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks Jef

Edit: 
If I place my code in one of the MouseListeners it works fine, but rather have it to be colored automatically instead of having to click each time.

```
 class Klaar extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {            
        Speler2[positie2].setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
}
```

Ps. my first language isn't english, I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `hokVerkleur` is actually getting called?  If it's not getting called, it really doesn't matter what the code is trying to do.  Debug your program using a debugger or `System.out.println("debug")` statements and figure out what *is* working.  Until you give us that information, you haven't put in enough effort to help us help you (see: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: When I use `System.out.println("Position "+loc);` in hokVerkleur it prints out the position which should be changed.

Comment: You should try .repaint() on your buttons right after you change the color.  Swing is inconsistent in that changing __some__ component properties automatically redraw the component, but changing other properties don't.

Comment: Also look at the documentation of [setBackground](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)): it says that it is not guaranteed to paint the background.  It depends if the subclass of JComponent decides to do so or not.   I don't know if JButton ignores setBackground or not (not in the API).

Comment: Using `.repaint()` doesn't work. Dinner now, i'll take a look at the documentation after. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If I place my code in one of the MouseListeners it works fine:
```

agreed, if you change Color for JButton from BackGroung Task, then there any changes, you have some issues with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), your updated to the GUI is out of EDT,

1) then you have to wrap coloring JButtons into invokeLater();

```
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Speler2[loc].setBackground(Color.yellow);
            Speler2[positie2].setBackground(Color.gray);
        }
    });
```

2) but you have to solve by using regular Swing methods

2a) wrap your GUI rellated code to the [javax.swing.Action](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

2b) initialize your BackGroung Tasks from

- [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- `Runnble#Tread`

Comment: @stereofrog no problem with to give you my ... `1)` I voted that as off-topic, `2)` not your down-voter, down-voting is for Gods, `3)` your question was more than Native OS rellated question, `4)`  there I couldn't see real question about PL `5)` question is rellated for  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/  or  http://superuser.com/ `6)` maybe is true that your question would be moved to another forum (instead of close)

Comment: Made a runable thread. `public void actionThread() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                while (!stop) {
                    tegenspelerPositie();
                    Score();
                    eigenOgen();
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }`

Works as a charm now.

Comment: don't sleep that, I know that works, but only for one current Thread, if is there two or more Threads, then that againg freeze, wrap that to the invokeLater() :-)

Comment: Sorry again, where do I place the `invokeLater`?

Comment: wrap GUI rellated code to the invokeLater(), that about notifying EDT about changes to the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Made a runnable thread, works as a charm. Thanks for help everybody.

```
public void actionThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            while (!stop) {
                tegenspelerPositie();
                Score();
                eigenOgen();
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```